# Two list GridViewBuilder and ListViewBuilder on a single flutter screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I'm fresh new to flutter, so I'm trying to merge two different list. The first list is `GridView.builder()` and second is `ListView.builder()`. The first grid list scroll horizontal and second list view scroll vertical. When user scroll the second list the hole screen start scrolling.

Comment: so you don't want the entire screen to scroll, you want the `GridView()` to still be visible when you scroll the `ListView()` ?

Comment: I want the gridView() not visible. For example the foodpanda home screen.

Answer (score -1):

You can Wrap your `ListView.builder()` and `GridView.builder()` with a `Column()` and a `SingleChildScrollView()` This way you can warp multiple scroll views within a Column(), just make sure to set the physics to `NeverScrollablePhysics()` if the scroll Direction is the same.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
      children :[ 
          GrdiView.builder(
              axis: Axis.Horizontal
              itemBuilder:(_, index){
                     ...
                  }
               ),
           ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
              shrinkWarp: true,
               itemBuilder:(_, index){
                     ...
                  }
                ),
              ],
           ),
      );
```

Hope this solves your issue.